# Ubuntu 21.04 NetworkManager.service fails

Tags: networking, network-manager, 21.04

I am facing certain issues with the NetworkManager service. It fails randomly, and I'm left with no internet connection unless I restart the machine. Restarting the NetworkManager service using either `sudo service NetworkManager restart` or `sudo systemctl restart systemd-networkd` used to solve the problem before, but they don't work now. Restarting the machine is the only option left to get back the internet connection.

This happens when I try to restart the NetworkManager service:

```
$ sudo service NetworkManager restart
Failed to restart NetworkManager.service: Unit NetworkManager.service failed to load properly: Transport endpoint is not connected.
See system logs and 'systemctl status NetworkManager.service' for details.
```

Checking the systemctl status, I get this:

```
$ systemctl status NetworkManager.service
● NetworkManager.service - Network Manager
     Loaded: error (Reason: Unit NetworkManager.service failed to load properly: Transport endpoint is not connected.)
     Active: inactive (dead) since Wed 2021-08-18 09:05:22 IST; 12min ago
       Docs: man:NetworkManager(8)
    Process: 1186 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 1186 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Aug 18 09:04:52 ashish-Inspiron-7570 NetworkManager[1186]: <info>  [1629257692.0857] caught SIGTERM, shutting down normally.
Aug 18 09:04:54 ashish-Inspiron-7570 NetworkManager[1186]: <info>  [1629257694.1067] device (wlp3s0): state change: activated -> deactivating (reason 'unmanaged', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 18 09:04:56 ashish-Inspiron-7570 NetworkManager[1186]: <info>  [1629257696.5316] device (wlp3s0): state change: deactivating -> unmanaged (reason 'removed', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Aug 18 09:04:56 ashish-Inspiron-7570 NetworkManager[1186]: <info>  [1629257696.5512] dhcp4 (wlp3s0): canceled DHCP transaction
Aug 18 09:04:56 ashish-Inspiron-7570 NetworkManager[1186]: <info>  [1629257696.5513] dhcp4 (wlp3s0): state changed bound -> done
Aug 18 09:04:56 ashish-Inspiron-7570 NetworkManager[1186]: <info>  [1629257696.7884] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
Aug 18 09:04:56 ashish-Inspiron-7570 NetworkManager[1186]: <info>  [1629257696.7891] device (p2p-dev-wlp3s0): state change: disconnected -> unmanaged (reason 'removed', sys-iface-state: 'removed')
Aug 18 09:04:56 ashish-Inspiron-7570 NetworkManager[1186]: <info>  [1629257696.7922] device (docker_gwbridge): bridge port vethb8a76bb was detached
Aug 18 09:04:56 ashish-Inspiron-7570 NetworkManager[1186]: <info>  [1629257696.7922] device (vethb8a76bb): released from master device docker_gwbridge
Aug 18 09:05:22 ashish-Inspiron-7570 systemd[1]: NetworkManager.service: Succeeded.
```

I have posted the `journalctl -xe` logs on: https://pastebin.com/vi8f4eSj

Can anyone help me identify what is failing and how to restart the failing component, so as to get back my internet connection without having to reboot my machine.

Comment: anything useful in [this reference](https://www.linuxfordevices.com/tutorials/ubuntu/restart-networking-on-ubuntu)?

Comment: @24601 No, this didn't solve my issue

Comment: I am having the same issue after upgrading from 20.10 to 21.04.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same confusing ***Transport endpoint is not connected*** error as well when issuing `systemctl restart NetworkManager` and was able to resolve it (on a guess) using `systemctl deaemon-reload`.

Comment: Thanks! I will try this when I encounter the same issue. Currently, everything works fine for me.